# Value of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer' cannot be converted to 'System.Type

Tags: vb.net, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm working on a custom TFS Build workflow based on the code found in two blogs:

- http://www.theringworx.com/blog/?p=494
- https://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/tfs2010-retrieve-associated-workitems-to-changesets-tfs-api/

When I implement the VB.Net code within my XAML workflow, I'm currently getting the following errors on build runtime:

> The build process failed validation. Details:
>
> Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1:
>   DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Compiler
>   error(s) encountered processing expression "TFSService".
>
> Value of type
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer'
>   cannot be converted to 'System.Type'.
>
> Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1:
>   DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Compiler
>   error(s) encountered processing expression "TFS.GetService(Of
>   VersionControlServer)();".
>
> End of expression expected.

I've traced the error down to this section of code (Simplified from XAML):

```
TFS=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollectionFactory(New Uri("MyTeamsTFSServer"))
TFSService = TFS.GetService(Of VersionControlServer)()
```

I've tried changing the type of TFSService from both Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer and System.Type without success.

From what I can tell the error is occurring in the "Of VersionControlServer".

Has anyone ever encountered this? And if so how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the URL I was using, I made a typo when I was entering it in. Yay for descriptive error messages...

I found this while I was checking my authentication using the two methods:

```
TFS.HasAuthenticated
TFS.Authenticate();
```

My code blew out when I was running the Authenticate() method.